# Put text on top of a div

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am trying to put a text/title on top of a div. I indicate it in red in the image but I can't do it.

[My image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfwFr.jpg)

My code:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col col-md-1">
      <img src="assets/icons/intercambiar.png" alt="intercambiar" />
    </div>
    <div class="col col-md-4 border border-white border-4" style="background-color: rgb(22, 111, 212); color: white;"> 01-15-12-03
    </div>
    <div class="col col-md-4 border border-white border-4" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: black;">

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Thank you

I have tried with the label tag but it scrolls everything.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-md-1">
      <img src="assets/icons/intercambiar.png" alt="intercambiar" />
    </div>
    <div class="col col-md-4">
      <label>text 1</label>
      <div class="border border-white border-4" style="background-color: rgb(22, 111, 212); color: white">
        01-15-12-03
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-md-4">
      <label>text 2</label>
      <div class="border border-white border-4" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: black">
        01-15-12-03
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the `::before` attribute in CSS:

```
.div::before{
    content: "[YOUR TEXT]";
    top: -50px;
    left: 50px;
}
```

You have to adjust the top and left to your div.

Comment: you might want to edit your answer, as this alone won't give a result like the OP image. I believe you need `display` too

Answer (score 0):

Add another row div before your content and add your labels

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col col-md-1"></div>
      <div class="col col-md-4">Label 1</div>
      <div class="col col-md-4">Label 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col col-md-1">
      <img src="assets/icons/intercambiar.png" alt="intercambiar" />
    </div>
    <div class="col col-md-4 border border-white border-4" style="background-color: rgb(22, 111, 212); color: white;"> 01-15-12-03
    </div>
    <div class="col col-md-4 border border-white border-4" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: black;">

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: This will result in weird stacking on mobile where the divs aren’t next to their associated labels.

Comment: @Levidps that is its own problem with relatively minor changes to incorporate. OP didn't mention mobile so I didn't take that into account